# Problem with model associations (1st rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I am developing a small mass administration rails app for our church.
It shall allow the planning of future masses, essentially assigning different tasks to different ministrants (acolyte/server/altar boy?).

One should be able to select serving ministrants (through checkboxes) and assign a task to each ministrant (through option lists), per mass (it does not need to be the same every mass).

My questions are:
  1. How would the migrations look like? I.e. which fields of what type are required?
  2. How would the model associations look like? Currently, I am assuming 3 classes (Mass, Ministrant, Task).

I found this question: [Correct Model Data Structure? (My 1st Rails App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439966/correct-model-data-structure-my-1st-rails-app)
and it looks similar but I don't really know how to apply the solution on this example...

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 models: mass, ministrant and task.

In your console:

```
rails g model Mass date:datetime 
rails g model Ministrant name:string role:string
rails g model Task name:string ministrant_id:integer mass_id:integer
```

In your ruby files:

```
class Mass < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :tasks
   has_many :ministrants, :through => :tasks
end
class Ministrant < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tasks
   has_many :masses, :through => :tasks
end
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ministrant
   belongs_to :mass
end
```

Comment: That makes kind of sense, don't know what I was thinking...Thank you very much!